# MongoDB merge Array Elements inside an Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "410a7cb2-7ee1-4e7a-9fb7-fa651fcaa4e5", 
    "reqHistoryEvents" : [
        {
            "reqHistoryMsg" : "abcd", 
            "reqHistoryCreatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-27T08:18:30.850+0000"), 
           
        }, 
        {
            "reqHistoryMsg" : "EFGH ", 
            "reqHistoryCreatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-27T08:22:12.716+0000"), 
          
        }, 
        {
            "reqHistoryMsg" : "IJKL", 
            "reqHistoryCreatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-27T08:22:12.716+0000"), 
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert it to this :::::

```
{ 
    "_id" : "410a7cb2-7ee1-4e7a-9fb7-fa651fcaa4e5", 
    "reqHistoryEvents" : [
        {
            "reqHistoryMsg" : "abcd", 
            "reqHistoryCreatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-27T08:18:30.850+0000"), 
           
        }, 
        {
            "reqHistoryMsg" : ["EFGH ","IJKL"], 
            "reqHistoryCreatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-27T08:22:12.716+0000"), 
          
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically it will be based on the creation Timestamp. We need to merge the reqHistoryMsg if we have same reqHistoryCreatedAt.

I am not able to write the **mongo** query. Any help?

Comment: I tried projection but didn't get much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `reqHistoryEvents` array field.
2. `$group` - Group by `_id` and `reqHistoryEvents.reqHistoryCreatedAt` fields. Add `reqHistoryMsg` into an array.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id` field and form `reqHistoryEvents` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$reqHistoryEvents"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        reqHistoryCreatedAt: "$reqHistoryEvents.reqHistoryCreatedAt"
      },
      reqHistoryMsg: {
        $push: "$reqHistoryEvents.reqHistoryMsg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      reqHistoryEvents: {
        $push: {
          reqHistoryMsg: "$reqHistoryMsg",
          reqHistoryCreatedAt: "$_id.reqHistoryCreatedAt"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CJHJtTLkjS8)

Comment: how to sort the array elements. As you can se it is in decs order. @yongshun

Comment: You can have a look in this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xy5PtGaAI52)

Comment: Thanks Yong Shun. It is working.